# Nested loops with Pandas using too much memory

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops, igraph

I have a dataset of organizations that are linked by their shared relationships on various committees. The data is in this format (somewhat simplified):

```
organization name | committee name       | number of relationships
ABC Corporation   | Committee A          | 7
ACME Inc.         | Committee B          | 3
XYZ Corporation   | Committee A          | 2
```

This is currently in a `pandas` data frame with about 30k rows.

I need to modify the data frame, sort of invert it, so that I can do a network analysis in R using `igraph`. That analysis needs two `csv` files, one that lists all the nodes, and the other that lists all the 'edges' or relationships between the nodes. To do that right now, I'm using two nested loops with `itertuples` to build a new data frame that records how organizations are related to each other, i.e., they are on the same committees.

This is the code (excluding how I handle refining the data after importing and then exporting it after this):

```
list_ = []
node_list = []
for row_a in network_df.itertuples():
    for row_b in network_df.itertuples():
        node_list.append({'node':row_a[1]})
        if row_a[2] == row_b[2] && row_a[1] != row_b[1]:
            temp_dict = {'from':row_a[1],'to':row_b[1], 'rels':row_a[3]}
            list_.append(temp_dict)

edge_df = pd.DataFrame(list_)
node_df = pd.DataFrame(node_list)
```

Here's the problem: this process never finishes, pandas ends up taking up over 30GB of memory and eventually I just have to terminate the processes.

I know that iterating over a pandas data frame is doing it the wrong way, but I'm not sure how to invert this data without nesting loops. Is the solution to use native Python lists or dictionaries and use nested loops with those? Even with 30k rows it doesn't seem like it should take this kind of memory overhead.

Comment: Why are you building a `node_list` with almost a billion entries? You might have misplaced that `node_list.append` or something.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a `groupby`.

Comment: @user2357112 You're right on the misplaced `node_list`. I have my de-duplication at the end of the loop which is inefficient.

Comment: Maybe [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects) can help you with that.

Comment: @tchaymore could you improved the sample input dataset to few more entries and also add a sample output, that'll help in understanding the required `node` & `list` entries better.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with list.append.
you can use python's networkx package.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_frame(df, sorce_col_name, target_col_name)
```

once you get the graph, you can continue to use networkx or extract its nodes/wedges and save it to csv for further analysis

Comment: based on problem description, I guess `source` & `target` need to be transformed from a single column; am I correct @tchaymore?

Comment: @PhilChang I didn't try networkx but did try building a network using igraph in Python and it was still pretty slow.